# Is it possible to wrap the exit method successfully?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, exit

I'm currently using gcc 4.1.2 and I have a use case where I want to use the linker options to wrap the exit method. Let's immediately put aside all the typical responses/comments of, "Why would you even want to do that?"

What I want to know is if it's possible to even do this. I have wrapped other methods using the linker before without any issues. Below is a quick example of the __wrap_exit function I'm using:

```
void __wrap_exit(int _status)
{
   return;
}
```

When exit is called this wrapper is indeed called. However, the program hits a segmentation fault immediately after this __wrap_exit returns.

- Does gcc do something behind the scenes like raise a signal when exit
  is called even though the real exit function is not called and only
  the wrapper version is?
- Could some details of what's happening behind
  the scenes be provided as well?

Comment: Where is control supposed to go when you `return` from that function? Are you supposed to `exit()` in the function instead of `return`?

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't use `atexit()` for… whatever it is you're doing?

Comment: How about calling `_exit()` before `return`. I believe there are some platform specific expectations of what a program must do before it actually exits, but I'm not sure. For starters, `exit()` is require to run the exit handlers.

Comment: What about calling your wrap_exit function directly and making that call exit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gcc has a language extension attribute called `__noreturn__`.  In your `<stdlib.h>`, you probably have a declaration something like:

```
extern void exit (int __status) __THROW __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
```

This attribute represents a promise that the function never returns in the normal way.  (Maybe it ends the process, or maybe it `longjmp`s, or maybe it throws a C++ exception, or maybe it has an unending loop...)

So when compiling code that calls `exit`, gcc can make some optimizations, like maybe not bothering to set up and/or clean up stack pointers to make it possible to come back to the calling function.

For example, here's a simple function that calls a library function, then its assembly on x86 with no `-O` flag specified.

```
void func1(void) {
    srand(1);
}

.globl func1
        .type   func1,@function
func1:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $8, %esp
        subl    $12, %esp
        pushl   $1
        call    srand
        addl    $16, %esp
        leave
        ret
```

And an almost identical function that calls `exit` instead:

```
void func2(void) {
    exit(0);
}

.globl func2
        .type   func2,@function
func2:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $8, %esp
        subl    $12, %esp
        pushl   $0
        call    exit
```

It starts out the same, but then just skips the `addl`, `leave`, and `ret` instructions, which in `func1` tell the CPU how to go back to executing whatever function called `func1`.

When you sneakily replace `exit` and break this promise, the instruction pointer might go somewhere that doesn't have sensible code, or the stack structure might be invalid, etc.  In the example function `func2`, the function assembly actually ended at the call to `exit`, so when you return and the instruction pointer comes back, it will be pointing at whatever data happens to be next in the program image, not necessarily even executable code at all.