# Is it possible for a program to capture SIGTERM generated by the exit system call?

Tags: c, signals

The program I have is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    struct sigaction new_sa;
    struct sigaction old_sa;
    sigfillset(&new_sa.sa_mask);
    new_sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    new_sa.sa_flags = 0;
    int input;

    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &new_sa, &old_sa) == 0 && old_sa.sa_handler != SIG_IGN) {
        new_sa.sa_handler = NULL;
        sigaction(SIGTERM, &new_sa, 0);
    }

    printf("Pgm is running\n");
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter input\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if (!input) {
            /* I actually call a libraries API which calls exit()
             * Just calling exit here for simpilicity */
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to handle/ignore SIGTERM generated by exit system call. Is it possible?
There is no way for me to avoid calling exit since its actually a library call which is trying to exit the program which i want to avoid.

Comment: Are you sure that `exit` sends a SIGTERM signal? I've never heard of that before and running in gdb does not show a SIGTERM on `exit`.

Comment: Yes..looks like you are right. It is not sending SIGTERM.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [glibc source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/exit.c) for exit it looks like it isn't possible. But it might be if you're using another C std library.

You can do stuff at_exit but you can't prevent it.

**[edit]**

Everything below here is apparently not applicable for exit for the reasons in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519309/is-it-possible-to-wrap-the-exit-method-successfully).

If you use gnu ld it might be possible to override `__run_exit_handlers`, or `exit` for that matter, using the gnu ld `--wrap` option but I havn't tried it.

If you can use gnu ld you could do `--wrap exit` and then implement `__wrap_exit()` in your code. If you want to call `exit` after this you can access it through `__real_exit()`.
This is a gnu ld feature and I'm not sure how universally available it is.

Comment: Is it possible to replace exit() call in the library with some other function which does the same thing and which I can "catch"?

Comment: GNU ld has the --wrap option to do that. It might work. Se updated answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how i can solve the problem and avoid terminating the program? Should I send a signal in the wrapper exit() instead of calling real exit()?

Comment: That is correct, in your `__wrap_exit` you are free to do whatever. And since it replaces `exit()` if you do nothing in there the call to `exit` would just return.

Comment: This did not work since the __wrap_exit expects a call to __real_exit or else the program is crashing with SIGSEGV. Calling real exit just terminates the program and defeats the purpose.

Comment: That might be something your external lib does. What lib is it?

Comment: iproute2, I am created library out of the object files generated by iproute2

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly catch `SIGTERM`. But that's not the problem here. You want to override the `exit()` call.

This is not possible in any portable or standard compliant way. The `exit()` is one of the functions that's defined to *not* return to its caller. Typically, this is done using the `__attribute__((noreturn))` in gcc and C11 has introduced the macro `_Noreturn` for the same purpose.

Attempting to return from such function, like `exit()`, is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are few options, I can think of:

- Compile and replace with your function: `gcc -Dexit=not_exit file.c`
- Write a hook function for `exit()`. See [here](http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/08/lets-hook-a-library-function/) for an example. Implementing a hook function may not work at all since this *noreturn* has existed on most libc implementations before C11's `_Noreturn`.
- Use GNU's ld as suggested by @evading. I believe this equivalent to the above but the linker does half of the work for you.

Modifying `<stdlib.h>` to remove the `_Noreturn` (or its equivalent) attribute for the `exit()` function might make it work. None of these is guaranteed to work. We are already well into the UB land.

Other option is to an install `atexit()` handler, which might be useful if you want to do something before `exit()`.

A saner approach would be to modify the library if you to not call `exit()` but instead return a error code. In my opinion, either the library is badly designed that it randomly exits on its own or probably there's a good reason that the library exits (due to some unrecoverable error) and your application is not supposed to continue any further, which you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to run the library call in a child process with `fork`. This does not prevent the call to `exit` but might be a workaround if you want to handle the error yourself.

Following a tutorial [Fork, Exec and Process control](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html). I use pipes to send the result of the library call back if the call is successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
  int pipefd[2];
  pipe(pipefd); //Create pipe for communication
  pid_t pid = fork();  
  if (pid == 0){ //Child process
    close(pipefd[0]); // close the read-end of the pipe,
    printf("Run library here\n");
    //    exit(3); if failed
    int val=4; //Result of library call send to parent
    write(pipefd[1], &val, sizeof(val));
    close(pipefd[1]); // close the write-end of the pipe
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  else if (pid < 0){           
    printf("Failed to fork\n");
  }
  else{//Parent process
    close(pipefd[1]);
    printf("Parent process\n");
    int status=0;
    int pid=wait(&status);
    printf("The pid %d finished with status %d\n",pid,status);        
    if (status==EXIT_SUCCESS){//The library call was successful
      int val=2;
      read(pipefd[0],&val,sizeof(int)); //Read data from pipe and do something with it
      printf("Value %d received\n",val);
    }
    close(pipefd[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```