# Use of __attribute__((noreturn)) for the exit function declaration in 'user.h' of the xv6 source code?

Tags: c, xv6

In the `user.h`

https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/a1da53a5a12e21b44a2c79d962a437fa2107627c/user/user.h#L6

exit is only syscall defined this way
`int exit(int) __attribute__((noreturn));`
why this is needed for the exit function declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `noreturn` attribute is strictly required, but it helps.

The `noreturn` attribute tells the compiler that the `exit` function will never return.  In theory, this allows the compiler to better understand the possible code paths of any code that calls `exit`, so it can display more accurate warnings and optimize the code better.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519309/is-it-possible-to-wrap-the-exit-method-successfully) mentions simply returning from __wrap_exit() segfaults, so possibly the noreturn attribute is ignoring or altering the stack frame in some way, making return not possible -- or at least not without doing backtrace() and some further manipulation

Answer (score 2):

Attribute declarations such as that are an extension to the C language supported by some compilers.  That particular one marks the `exit()` function with the very unusual characteristic that it never returns to its caller.

Such marking is not *needed*, but it assists the compilers for which it is intended to optimize more effectively and / or to emit more accurate diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I think both the answers so far are very good to me ... I will accept David one just because it was temporarily the first.